# Installing Anaconda 2 Twice in Different Folders

Tags: python, anaconda

Is it possible to install Anaconda 2 twice in different folders without any issues?

I need an older version for one package and a newer one for another.

Comment: Yes, if you don't need to set the path-var. But to be honest: Don't do it. Anaconda's [environments](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) are exactly for use-cases like that!

Answer (score 1):

If your use case is only for using different versions for the same package, I would suggest to create different environments. For example, assume that you have a version for `pyqt` in your current environment, but you need a previous version for a dependency. The following command will create a new environment named `oldqt`, with version 4 of `pyqt`.

```
conda create -n oldqt pyqt=4
```

Afterwards, you can activate the new environment as below.

MacOS:

```
source activate oldqt
```

Windows

```
conda activate oldqt
```

Note that you need to install everything into your new environment, it is like a clean installation of anaconda. More information on conda environments is [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).

Comment: Actually, with conda 4.4 or higher, it should be `conda activate` on all platforms